# ng-repeat doesn't work using JSON data

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to show some recieved JSON-data on my website, here's controller:

```
angular.module('web')
  .controller('runController', function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('/#/runs')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      $scope.runs = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
   });
});
```

and then here's my html:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Runs</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="run in runs">
        <td>{{run.id}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And finally the JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "environment_id": 4, 
    "start_time": "13:11:10.781463", 
    "start_date": "2015-05-21", 
    "feature_id": 2, 
    "usecase_id": 4, 
    "id": 12
  }
]
```

Now when doing it this way the site shows the following error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: run in runs, Duplicate key: string:<, Duplicate value: <

When adding a `track by $index` in my html I get about 700 empty `<td>`'s.

Someone mentioned to deserialize the JSON data in my controller using  `$scope.runs = angular.fromJson(data);` but that leads to the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Is that just part of the array of json data you're getting or is there really just 1 object in the array?

Comment: @NexusDuck there's just 1 object

Comment: check in network the data, if is a valid json,

Comment: Both messages tell you that your JSON contains some `<` character. Are you REALLY sure the JSON result is what you expect it to be? Check your developer tools in your browser (F12, network tab) for the exact result of the Ajax call

Comment: @user3227295 jsonlint tells me it's valid

Comment: Show us your complete JSON data after success ajax call.

Comment: I just copied your code to this jsbin entry and saw that it works. The only change I made was to hardcode the JSON.

check if it's the right JSON or not ?

http://jsbin.com/bahuwe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not about the ng-repeat itself, but the $http.

I tried to duplicate the issue in my local machine and this is what I observed, Your $http.get() method is not able to get the JSON data from the server.

For example, modify your code like this

```
angular.module('web')
 .controller('runController', function($http, $scope) {
   $http.get('/#/runs')
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
     console.log( data );
     $scope.runs = data;
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     alert(data);
   });
});
```

I just added the `console.log(data)`, you could see that it might be giving  a 404 error ( that's the reason `angular.fromJson(data);` gave the JSON parse error )

The solution is to fix the url for the JSON. If it works, you should be able to see the `data` logged into the console properly. And, your code should work at that time.

Comment: I messed up with the url's in the whole project, thanks

Comment: Your welcome. Check line by line next time before going to the AngularJs error message

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "track by" in order to solve this.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="run in runs track by run.id">
    <td>{{run.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

> ngRepeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays
>
> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

For more details see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Assuming that id is unique for all records, we can track by "id"

Comment: Duplication of < type character indicate the http request returned some html, probably 404 so the issue will not be resolved by track by and as its an array of objects it shouldn't need it.